# Couchbase python module : failed to import

Tags: python, import, anaconda, couchbase, requirements

I installed `couchbase module` on anaconda using `pip`. It was succesfully installed, I tried to do it again and it said `requirement already satisfied`. In spite of this when I try to `import` using `anaconda`'s `idle` it doesn't work. Thanks for helping me it's an assignment due for very soon and I don't know how I'll do it without couchbase module. I already tried installing `couchbase_core` using `pip` and it says `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement couchbase_core (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for couchbase_coreERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement couchbase_core (from versions: none)`.
I'll show the error:

```
>>> from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'couchbase'
>>> import couchbase

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\enora\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\couchbase_core\__init__.py", line 43
    warnings.warn("Couldn't import SSL, TLS functionality may not be available")
UserWarning: Couldn't import SSL, TLS functionality may not be available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import couchbase
  File "C:\Users\enora\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\couchbase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import couchbase_core._bootstrap
  File "C:\Users\enora\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\couchbase_core\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import couchbase_core._libcouchbase as _LCB
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

^^

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: Looks like it imported fine. Now you get a warning about a dll in French

Comment: I'm using 3.7, anaconda's distribution, but I have several versions installed including a venv so I could use another. Yes, I think that's because I'm in France. It says specified module can't be found. ^^

Comment: I just saw using docker is recommended for using the python sdk do you think it would solve the problem? ^^

Comment: I don't think it imported fine, because I can't use any of the module's functions. How could I test if it was imported? ^^

Comment: Are you using the base/root Conda environment? That can lead to some issues, you should create a new environment for each project.